# Javascript exiting Onclick Function

Tags: javascript, logic

I would like to exit onclick, I've tried this code here, but I want it to be one click, placing one marker, not one click, infinite markers.

```
document.getElementById("addWater").onclick = function()
{
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
        function placeMarker(location) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: map
            });
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about mimicking the "once" function in jquery? Maybe you could try this approach

```
var a = false;
document.getElementById("addWater").onclick = function () {
    if (!a) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });

        function placeMarker(location) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        }

        a = true;
    }
}
```